# awk question - how print additional lines only for unique dates

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am a complete novice with AWK and trying to prepare input for another program with the AWK. I have data as per table below and I need to extract data from columns 5 to 10. Also, for each new date encountered (as stated in colums 1 and 2-4) I need to write a preceding command (`DATES`), please see below 'desired output'.

- Input example (`input.txt`) - *Note that the first commented line is for illustrative purposes only, and not present in the actual data.*

  ```
  #  1        2  3   4    5   6   7   8   9   10
  20071016    16 Oct 2007 A   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
  20071017    17 Oct 2007 A   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
  20071017    17 Oct 2007 B   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
  20071018    18 Oct 2007 C   X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
  ```
- Desired output (`out.txt`)

  ```
  DATES
  16 Oct  2007 /
  /
  WCONPROD
  A    X1 X2 X3  X3  X4  X5  /
  /
  DATES
  17 Oct  2007 /
  /
  WCONPROD
  A    X1 X2 X3  X3  X4  X5  /
  /
  WCONPROD
  B    X1 X2 X3  X3  X4  X5  /
  /
  DATES
  18 Oct 2007 /
  /
  WCONPROD
  C    X1 X2 X3  X3  X4  X5  /
  /
  ```

What I have problem with is to print `DATES` only once for each date if there are several lines with the same date. I found and modified the following AWK lines to get this far but i am struggling to have dates only once for each (new) date. I have made another column in an attempt to make AWK to look/compare column 1 with the previous but not sure how to implement this.

- `awk` command tried

  ```
  { printf "%-s\n%-s %s  %s %s\n%s\n", "DATES", $2,$3,$4,"/","/" 
    print "\nWCONPROD\n"
    printf "   %-s \t%s %s %s  %s  %s  %s  %s\n%s\n\n", $5, $6, $7, $8, $8, $9, $10, "/","/" }
  ```
- If I run these AWK commands then I have `DATES` printed for each row while as shown below:

  ```
  DATES
  16 Oct  2007 /
  /
  WCONPROD
  A    X1 X2 X3  X3  X4  X5  /
  /
  DATES
  17 Oct  2007 /
  /
  WCONPROD
  A    X1 X2 X3  X3  X4  X5  /
  /
  ## i want to remove (not to print) these/next 3 lines as this date was already declared earlier
  DATES
  17 Oct  2007 /
  /
  WCONPROD
  B    X1 X2 X3  X3  X4  X5  /
  /
  DATES
  18 Oct 2007 /
  /
  WCONPROD
  C    X1 X2 X3  X3  X4  X5  /
  /
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following `awk` program should do the trick:

```
awk '$1!=lastdate {printf "DATES\n%s %s %s /\n/\n",$2,$3,$4; lastdate=$1}
     {print "WCONPROD"; for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,OFS; print "/\n/"}' input.txt
```

This will compare the value of the first column with the content of the variable `lastdate`, and if they differ, print the specified "header" section. It will also update `lastdate` to the newly-found date on the line.

For all lines, it will print the `WCONPROD` string, then fields 5 to (whatever many you have), separated by the "output field separator" (default is a single space, change with `-v OFS='whatever'` command-line argument to suit your needs), and followed by the `/ <newline> /` pattern.

Output for your example:

```
DATES
16 Oct 2007 /
/
WCONPROD
A X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 /
/
DATES
17 Oct 2007 /
/
WCONPROD
A X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 /
/
WCONPROD
B X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 /
/
DATES
18 Oct 2007 /
/
WCONPROD
C X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 /
/
```

Comment: Thank you very much! for some reason all i am getting is this if through the console.
DATES
   /
/
WCONPROD
/
/
I will try to troubleshoot
thnaks

Comment: Did the source file  originate on a windows machine? If so, you may have to run it through `dos2unix`

Comment: thank you very much! it worked now! 
you see who you are dealing with ...

Comment: No problem, and don't belittle yourself. We all had to learn it at some point, and these types of pitfall are often subtle. If the answer worked for you, you may want to consider [accepting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so that others facing a similar issue can find it more easily.

Comment: Thank you very much!
this answer is more than i hoped for!